# Show div on focus, but close when click anywhere on page

Tags: jquery

I have a div that appears underneath my search box. Though I cannot click the link within the div that appears on focus - as the search form is no longer "focused".

I'm looking to make the div appear when I'm typing in the input box and make the links clickable, but hide the div when I click anywhere else.

```js
$("#searchInput").focusin(function() {
        $("#searchResults").show();
    }).focusout(function () {
        $("#searchResults").hide();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="d-flex" action="/search">
  <input id="searchInput" class="form-control me-2 border-0 search-box" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
</form>
<div class="result_box">
  <ul class="list-group" id="searchResults">
  <a href="google.com" target="_blank">Test Search Result</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What's the best way to go about achieving this functionality?

Comment: so you didnt care of focus in/out? you want the link appears when you have at least one char in search box ?

Comment: Yeah, open it on focus in/out. But allow clicking on the links within the box when you're focusing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be not the perfect solution but it works.

```js
$("#searchInput").focusin(function() {
        $("#searchResults").show();
    });

$(document).on('click', function(event)
{
    let target = event.target;
    if(!$(target).hasClass("link") && !$(target).hasClass("search-box"))
         $("#searchResults").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="d-flex" action="/search">
  <input id="searchInput" class="form-control me-2 border-0 search-box" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
</form>
<div class="result_box">
  <ul class="list-group" id="searchResults">
  <a class = "link" href="google.com" target="_blank">Test Search Result</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you click the link in your solution? I cannot open the page.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the link class to the link. Normally this should work now. I am not sure if you can link to external page in the snippet